# Django admin missing static files when using gunicorn web server

Tags: django

When I run my project with `runserver`, django admin is showing with static files. Everything looks pretty.

But when I run my project with the `gunicorn` web server, static files for the django admin are not found:

```
Not Found: /
Not Found: /favicon.ico
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/login.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/dashboard.css
```

Why are these static files not served out of the box?

What steps should I make to serve the static files for django admin via `gunicorn`?

I'm using Django 1.9 with python 3.4

Comment: Don't be intimidated by down-votes or snooty comments.  This is not a stupid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to collect all static files via `manage.py collectstatic` command. More information in the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic

Comment: i am getting `Refused to apply style from 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/admin/css/base.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled` error what to do ?